# How I can know the IP address of other users logged at the same remote machine?

Tags: linux, bash, networking, solaris

I can see the names of other users on the remote machine with the `who` command... **I'd also like know the IP address of those users...**

I was trying with the commands `/sbin/ifconfing` and `netstat` but I could not get positive results...

I need this solution compatible both with Linux and Unix...

Is there a command with that utility? Do I need to write a script or use a kind of pipes?

Comment: Just to be clear, `who` doesn't tell you about users on the same *network*, just users **logged in** to the same machine as you.

Comment: When I log in a distant machine, `who` gives me my origin machine name on both linux and solaris (last field, between parenthesis, when logged in locally from X I get the X display). Getting the IP from that should be easy (`nslookup`, `host`)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Try the `w` command, part of the [`procps`](http://procps.sourceforge.net/) package.

```
$ w
 21:12:09 up 6 days,  7:42,  1 user,  load average: 0.27, 1.08, 1.64
USER     TTY      FROM              LOGIN@   IDLE   JCPU   PCPU WHAT
h3xx     pts/11   192.168.1.3      21:12    2.00s  0.04s  0.04s -bash
```

Comment: Is the `procps` package available in Unix (specifically Solaris)?

Answer (score 5):

The `who` manpage on my Debian Linux system shows there's an `--ips` option to display IPs instead of hostnames.

Comment: I'll try that option when I'll back to the Solaris network lab. In my Xubuntu system doesn't show the IP address

Comment: I don't have this flag on Gentoo either; it looks like it was added by Debian in 5.96-3 as part of [bug 363126](http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=363126)

Comment: This flag doesn't exist on my SuSe system either.

Comment: CentOS 6.5 doesn't have that option either.

Comment: no `--ips` option on arch too

Answer (score 1):

`who` is the command I use, but it is not 100% reliable.  The resulting names are from the PTR record for the IP address.  There may or may not be a matching A record for the name.

Data from `ps` and `netstat` can be integrated if you have root privileges.  Otherwise you can only make educated guesses which connection belongs to which process.

There are other tools which can be used, but I haven't found any programs that have consistent parameters and output across UNIX/Linux flavors.

Answer (score 1):

On some old UNIX (i.e. SCO OpenServer Release 5.0.7), the `w` command is a good start, but the IP address is not output by default.  Command arguments are sometimes required.  From the `man` page:

```
-x
   Print out the hostname. This option cannot be used with
   the -u option.

-X
   Print out full hostnames. This option implies the -x
   option. Hostnames printed by the -x option are truncated
   to fit into a field; hostnames printed by the -X option
   are not truncated.
```

For example:

```
$ w
  2:39pm  up 2 days, 11:07,  1 user,  load average: 0.00, 0.00, 0.00
User     Tty       Login@   Idle   JCPU   PCPU  What
minime   ttyp0     2:31pm      -      -      -  w
$ w -x
  2:39pm  up 2 days, 11:07,  1 user,  load average: 0.00, 0.00, 0.00
User     Tty       Login@   Idle   JCPU   PCPU Hostname           What
minime   ttyp0     2:31pm      -      -      - 192.168.36.188     w -x
```